Should I use fastForEach on ImmutableList kotlinx.collections?
Should I use fast functions (e.g., fastForEach from androidx.compose.ui.util) with ImmutableList from kotlinx.collections.immutable?
I'm working on a Jetpack Compose project where I use ImmutableList from kotlinx.collections.immutable. I’ve come across fast functions like fastForEach in androidx.compose.ui.util that claim to optimize iteration by reducing overhead.
My question is:
Is it advisable to use these fast functions with ImmutableList?
What are the potential benefits and drawbacks of doing so/ or maybe ImmutableList handle that already?

If you're looking for performance, I'm not sure I'd necessarily consider kotlinx.collections.immutable...

@LouisWasserman can explain why?

The kotlinx.collections.immutable collections trade performance in the common case for the ability to construct modified versions of the immutable collection efficiently.  For about 99% of applications, that's a bad trade.
